# Logstash and Kibana installers for Windows

Tags: windows, logstash, kibana

I haven't found a pure Windows-only installation for [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) and [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/).

I am starting to dig into using Logstash to manage log4j logs as input.

Can anybody point me to pure Windows-only (using only Windows tools) installation for a standalone Windows developer machine?

Comment: you don't need an installer for logstash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kibana can easily be installed in IIS on windows. (tested IIS 7.5, windows 7).
All you need to do is just extract the kibana root folder to your root IIS folder for your
default site (its in c:\inetpub\wwwroot by default).

You'll only need to add mimetype .json text/html in the IIS console for your site for loading kibana json dashboards.

Thats it! its no big deal really, 5 seconds of work.

Can't help you about logstash as i didnt use it myself. Instead, i'm planning to use a .net log4net ElasticSearch appender to write logs directory to ElasticSearch.